Bitbake: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc not found
i am using ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, bitbake 2.8.0, poky scarthgap branch and beaglebone black. I have created my own layer and my own helloworld recipe which contain a helloworld.c. I would like to execute it in beaglebone black. When i am trying to execute 'bitbake helloworld' i am getting the error arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found.
Do i have to install arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc or am i missing something else?
Here is the helloworld.bb file:
DESCRIPTION = "Hello World application"

SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"


SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}

# Disable default dependency checks (including SHA256)
INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

I have tried to find the package and install it but I couldn't find a clear solution.

Did you try removing INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS ?

its solved now!
I had to remove the instruction INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1" from the recipe because this variable means that default dependencies are not required which is not correct.I had to remove the instruction INHERIT += "rm_work" from local.conf file because this instruction remove all intermediate build artifacts to save space.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
